# HealtKit: how to determine original unit HKQuantitySample was stored in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

If I am accessing a user's weight (or any other HKQuantitySample), how can I determine what unit the user originally stored the weight in?

Answer (score 3):

HealthKit does not expose the original unit that was used when the sample was saved.  However, if you'd like to display the quantity in the unit that the user prefers for samples of that type I'd recommend checking out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKHealthStore/preferredUnitsForQuantityTypes:completion:) for the `preferredUnitsForQuantityTypes:completion:` method on `HKHealthStore`.